Python subprocess with long bash scripts
Im using this code to run some bash commands using Python script:
cmd = 'findmnt --kernel /tmp | grep nosuid 2>/dev/null'

Sbp = subprocess.call(cmd ,
                shell=True,
                executable="/bin/bash",
                text=True)

That works fine, but sometimes I need to execute some complex commands like these:
grep -Eis "(\\\v|\\\r|\\\m|\\\s|$(grep \'^ID=\' /etc/os-release | cut -d= -f2 | sed -e \'s/\"//g\'))\" /etc/motd 2>/dev/null

How can I assign these complex commands to the variable with these spaces and characters?
I'm trying to find some PowerShell Here-string or ScriptBlock analog. Example in Powershell:
$cmd = @'
grep -Eis "(\\\v|\\\r|\\\m|\\\s|$(grep \'^ID=\' /etc/os-release | cut -d= -f2 | sed -e \'s/\"//g\'))\" /etc/motd 2>/dev/null
'@

or
$ScriptBlock = {grep -Eis "(\\\v|\\\r|\\\m|\\\s|$(grep \'^ID=\' /etc/os-release | cut -d= -f2 | sed -e \'s/\"//g\'))\" /etc/motd 2>/dev/null}

What is the best and simple way to understand this with examples in Python?

surround the string with triple quotes and use r in front of it to prevent Python from interpreting the backlsashes. r"""..."""

You could do that grep | cut | sed in python itself rather than spawning a shell at all.

@kindall thanks a lot, works fine
